# Img vertical align to ul?

Tags: image, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical align the logo image to the bottom of the my navigation menu. I've tried vertical-align:text-bottom, but the vertical-align doesn't seem to work for me, because the ul not works like the normal p tag.
Anybody who can help me?

```
        <a href="index.php">
            <img id="logo" alt="logo" src="http://dyrholmkantinedrift.dk/img/kantinedrift_logo01.png" height="50">
        </a>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Pellentesque">Pellentesque</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Aliquam">Aliquam</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Morbi">Morbi</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The css:

```
            header img {
                float:left;
                position:absolute;
            }

            ul {
                height:50px;
                position:relative;
              }

            ul li {
                display:inline-block;
                bottom:0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nh6NZ/

The key is you need to use `display:inline-block` instead of floating if you want to vertical-align those elements.and Also float and position absolute can't be used together.